# Appending to root using XMLSerializer in Android

Tags: xml, xmlserializer, android-xml

I'm appending to a serializer in a loop, however having problems placing a root element.

Using this code:

```
serializer = serializer.startTag(null, StaticClass.ROOT);

for (int i = 0; i < categoriesCursor.getCount(); i++) {
    appendToCategoriesXml(serializer, id, name, kind, uses);
    categoriesCursor.moveToNext();
}
```

I don't understand why the root being put automatically right after first list element, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
  <root>
    <category id="1">
      <name>fun</name>
      <kind>exp</kind>
      <uses>0</uses>
    </category>
  </root>
    <category id="2">
      <name>food</name>
      <kind>exp</kind>
      <uses>15</uses>
    </category>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please show what happens in the `appendToCategoriesXml()`? I also wonder where down the code you call the `serializer.endTag()`. is it right after the `for` loop?

Comment: I just discovered the problem... it was stupid. I did EndDocument at every iteration, so it ended root right after first one... I'd delete this question if not your comment :)

Comment: Talking to someone else other than yourself about the problem often opens your eyes just enough to figure it our yourself :) That said, never regret asking a question, especially the one that helped you find the answer

Comment: wise words, however frequentially asked stupid question make your account banned on stackoverflow my friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered the problem... it was stupid. I did EndDocument at every iteration, so it ended root right after first one...